# Why don't anonymous functions work with maps in clojure?

Tags: clojure, maps

When I do the following it works:

```
user> (#(+ % 8) 7)
15
```

But why doesn't this work?

```
user> (#({:a %}) 7)
Execution error (ArityException) at user/eval74597$fn (form-init937950372947324749.clj:760).
Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

Expected result: {:a 7}

Answer (score 7):

Anon-fn with `#()` are a reader macro.  If you look at the code generated, it becomes obvious, why it does not work (the body is called):

```clj
user=> '#({:a %})
(fn* [p1__8266#] ({:a p1__8266#}))
```

So the arg is passed as key for one map and it's called at once, since that is what the reader macro does.  The usually safe way around this is using `do`, when you want to use the data literals:

```
user=> (#(do {:a %}) 7)
{:a 7}
```

Or, of course, using the various functions like `hash-map` to create the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the way the anonymous function shorthand expands, which on a `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap` happens to be invalid.

The `#(+ % 8)` shorthand is a macro that expands to:

```clj
(fn* [x] (+ x 8))
```

When you call it with `#({:a %})` it expands to:

```clj
(fn* [x] ({:a x}))
```

Which tries to invoke the map as a function without its required arguments. Alternatively you can use `assoc` to achieve the desired result:

```clj
user=> (#(assoc {} :a %) 7)
{:a 7}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thumbnail I've edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The same reason this gives the same error:

```
user> (defn foo [x] ({:a x}))
#'user/foo

user> (foo 1)
Execution error (ArityException) at user/foo (form-init8381914060375571593.clj:54).
Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
```

You're not the only one to get tripped up by this. The issue is explained here: https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_gotcha

You can either use the longer way of creating anonymous functions:

```
user> ((fn [x]{:a x}) 7)
{:a 7}
```

Or use a function to create the map dynamically:

```
user> (#(hash-map :a %) 7)
{:a 7}
```